# :not css selector in javascript doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to disable scroll on the document while a search is active. Only the results should have a scroll. Also, everything else besides the results should be `opacity: 0.85` since the results are in a `position: fixed` div overlaying the other content. here is the javascript function that runs when a search starts and ends:

```
if (isSearchActive) {
      document
        .querySelectorAll(":not(.active-search)")
        .forEach((e) => (e.style.opacity = ".85"));
      document
        .querySelectorAll(":not(.active-search)")
        .forEach((e) => (e.style.overflow = "hidden"));
    } else {
      document
        .querySelectorAll(":not(.active-search)")
        .forEach((e) => (e.style.opacity = "1"));
      document
        .querySelectorAll(":not(.active-search)")
        .forEach((e) => (e.style.overflow = "auto"));
    }
```

But for some reason, everything including the `.active-search` div is getting affected by this selector. What would be the right way to doing it?

Comment: it would be easier if you provide a mini example code to illustrate your question please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Styles are inherited. So if the container of `.active-search` is missing the class, the style will be inherited by the `.active-search` element.

Comment: I would think the selector would be matching against the body tag potentially

Comment: Would be easier making the active search an overlay - this smells of X/Y problem

Comment: Are you aware that `document.querySelector()` only returns the **first** match?

Comment: whats happening is that javascript is injecting `style="opacity: 0.85; overflow: 'hidden'"` only to the `html tag` @ÁlvaroGonzález, right, now I understand why this is happening. so what is my solution. `querySelectorAll` doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by [Barmar's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824666/not-css-selector-in-javascript-doesnt-seem-to-work#comment109353388_61824666). 
Since you cant have a lower opacity on the parent element then the child element so the correct selector would be `document.querySelectorAll('#root :not(.active-search)')`